# Template type is not "seen" by the compiler inside a lambda

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates, c++11

```
template<typename Wcf, typename Wdb>
void ComputeGenericDropCount(const function<void(Wdb *, int)> &func)
{
    Wcf::ForEach([&](Wcf *wcf) {
        Wdb *wdb = Wdb::Find(wcf->sourceId); // <--- ERROR
            // error C2653: 'Wdb' : is not a class or namespace name


        if(wdb)
            func(wdb, wcf->itemCount);
    });
}
```

It's weird because it seems to "see" `Wcf` without problems, I even use it: `wcf->itemCount`.

Is there any workaround or reason why this is happening?

Comment: it recognizes wcf because it is the parameter passed by reference to your lambda. Isn't it ? However as `Wdb::Find` seems to be a public static function, it don't see any reason not to be used in the body of the lambda. Could you confirm that `Wdb::Find` is a public static function of class Wdb, i mean the one you instanciate your template upon ?

Comment: I think you should ask this on microsofts VC2010++ forum, it could potentially be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why it doesn't work. But here is a workaround.

```
template<typename Wcf, typename Wdb>
void ComputeGenericDropCount(const function<void(Wdb *, int)> &func)
{
    auto my_find = Wdb::Find; // allows lambda to "capture" the correct function.
    Wcf::ForEach([&](Wcf *wcf) 
    {
        Wdb *wdb = my_find(wcf->sourceId);     

        if(wdb)
            func(wdb, wcf->itemCount);
    });
}
```

Comment: `auto my_find = Wdb::Find;` I love this ! Really nice way to handle pointers to member function without heavy syntax. Really nice ! Thanx for the proposal.