# Scope in a lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class Type>
struct X
{
    void run()const
    {//Why on earth this doesn't work?
        [&]()
        {
            Type::alloc();
        };
    }
    void run_1()const
    {//if this does
        Type::alloc();
    }
};

struct T
{

    static void alloc()
    {}
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    X<T> x;
    x.run_1();
    return 0;
}
```

AFAIC lambda is a unnamed fnc, so if that's true why run doesn't compile and run_1 does?
Using VS2010 sp beta1.

Comment: My guess is that, whichever way you cut it, that lambda function is not a member of X, even if it is declared in `run()`.  It has nothing to do with the enclosing class.

Comment: Could you please, give us the compilation error returned by VS2010.

Comment: It's `error C2653: 'Type' : is not a class or namespace name`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template type is not "seen" by the compiler inside a lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326674/template-type-is-not-seen-by-the-compiler-inside-a-lambda)

Comment: possible duplicate of [templates, typename, lambda -> dependent names not dependent??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589056/templates-typename-lambda-dependent-names-not-dependent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pass it in to the lambda:

```
    void run()const
    {//Why on earth this doesn't work?
        auto alloc = Type::alloc;
        [&]()
        {
            alloc();
        };
    }
```

Comment: @Moo-Juice so it isn't really true what "they" say about lambdas that lambdas are identicall to fnc with the only exception of not having name? I really like first line in body of this fnc. Thanks. And as for lambdas? Dissapointment. You can use them in only simplest situations but who needs more advanced use have to use "named" fncs. Dissapointment. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Moo-Juice in my "real example" it doesn't really work though. Reason? alloc from Type is overloaded.

Comment: @There, can you paste some of that (or example code) on to the end of your question to give me an idea?

Comment: @Moo-Juice too many lines and two many headers. The Implementation is a separate header the Alloc is a typedef from different header and memoryManager is again in different header. But what you can try, if you really wanna check it make alloc overloaded and you should have "the same" result as I.

Comment: @There, I'm assuming the error you get is `error C3535: cannot deduce type for 'auto' from 'overloaded-function'` ?

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit I am not quite sure, but I think is only a VS 2010 limitation and it should compile fine in C++0x (cf. [templates, typename, lambda -> dependent names not dependent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589056/templates-typename-lambda-dependent-names-not-dependent/4593286#4593286)). I think the mechanics of what you see are like following:

When defining template, types defined by template parameters are not "fully fledged" typenames in some aspects. One example demonstrating this is that while someone might expect `X<Foo>::Type` (with X from your example) to return Foo, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You have to call the lambda. It is a functor so you need a () at the end of it to effectively call the lambda.</del>

```
/* Code does NOT answer question above...
void run()const
    {//Why on earth this doesn't work?
        [&]()
        {
            Type::alloc();
        }(); //very important parenthesis if you wish to call the lambda
    }*/
```

I seem to have misread the question. Sorry.

---

But there is already a similar post on SO [Template type is not "seen" by the compiler inside a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326674/template-type-is-not-seen-by-the-compiler-inside-a-lambda)

And here is another link that refers to the same problem, with a quote from the standard about this.
[templates, typename, lambda -> dependent names not dependent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589056/templates-typename-lambda-dependent-names-not-dependent/4593286#4593286)

Comment: @RedX did you check your answer before posted?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Does it have C++0x support?

Comment: This would not explain why it does not compile.

Comment: Only c++0x does have lambda support... Without that the compiler will not understand the syntax?

Comment: @RedX, he is saying that it does not compile.  I think he is well aware that it is for C++0x.  Pay attention.

Comment: @RedX does "Using VS2010 sp beta1" mean anything to you?

Comment: Yes it does, sorry. It just seemed weird, that it was having trouble instanciating such a simple lambda. But i guess the correct answer is the one that Moo-Juice gave. Maybe template arguments do not carry into lambdas since they are instanciated as Functors outside the function in which they are declared.

Comment: @There Here is a similar question, maybe it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326674/template-type-is-not-seen-by-the-compiler-inside-a-lambda